# How to merge separate logical volumes in to one physical disk?

Tags: virtio

i can see my server disk like this

Disk /dev/vda: 50.0 GB

Disk /dev/vdb: 50.0 GB

I need to combine these two virtual block devices into single physical disk as 100GB. I have installed CentOS 7.

Are there any method to combine it?

Answer (score 0):

*(Forget this, I misread the question and assumed there were two partitions on one drive)*
You can delete the second partition and resize the first one, resizing the filesystem either afterwards or during the partition resize operation (gparted supports that). However, you would need to first backup the filesystem currently residing on the second partition, so you can restore the data to the enlarged filesystem afterwards. If you currently use less than 50% of the available disk space, you can copy the files from /dev/vdb to /dev/vda directly before doing the repartition/resize.

Comment: I guess those are two different hard drives, so that is probably impossible

Comment: You're right, I misread the question. So LVM would probably be a better option, but a bit more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

You do indeed want to use LVM. Here is a diagram to the  steps to perform that I got from the StackExchange community and a link to detailed instructions
http://www.techbrown.com/linux-lvm-logical-volume-centos-7-rhel-7.shtml

1. Create a physical volume on the first hard drive, and another physical volume on the second hard drive.
2. Create a new volume group, assigning both physical volumes to it.
3. Create a new logical volume in that volume group.
4. Create a new ext3 filesystem in that logical volume.

[image: LVM]